# Inference on pre-trained ONNX model from Unity ml-agents in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx, ml-agent

I have a pre-trained model from Unity's ml-agents. Now I'm trying to do inference with that model in python using TensorFlow. For this, I use [TensorFlow Backend for ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow) to save the ONNX model as a SavedModel so I can later load this model. The code used for saving the model is

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load(model_path)  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model, logging_level='DEBUG')
tf_rep.export_graph(output_path)
```

the code for loading the model and running a test example

```
imported = tf.saved_model.load(
     model_dir, tags=None, options=None
)
f = imported.signatures["serving_default"]
print(f(visual_observation_0=tf.cast(forward, tf.float32), 
          visual_observation_1=tf.cast(body, tf.float32)))
```

Now there are a few issues.

1. the output of the test has 6 output values . (see image below for a visual graph of ONNX file)
2. I got the following message when trying to save the model (see debug info below)

Not sure what's going on here any help much appreciated
[image: Visual model]

```
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op Celu in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ConcatFromSequence in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op ConstantFill in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ConvInteger in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of CumSum in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of DequantizeLinear in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,267 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of Det in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of DynamicQuantizeLinear in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op Einsum in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of GatherElements in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of GatherND in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op GreaterOrEqual in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op ImageScaler in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of IsInf in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,268 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Unknown op LessOrEqual in domain 'ai.onnx'.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of MatMulInteger in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of Mod in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of NonMaxSuppression in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of QLinearConv in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of QLinearMatMul in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of QuantizeLinear in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of Range in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,269 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of Resize in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ReverseSequence in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of RoiAlign in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of Round in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ScatterElements in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ScatterND in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceAt in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceConstruct in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceEmpty in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceErase in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceInsert in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SequenceLength in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,270 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of SplitToSequence in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03,271 - onnx-tf - DEBUG - Fail to get since_version of ThresholdedRelu in domain '' with max_inclusive_version=9. Set to 1.
2021-03-24 17:52:03.273323: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-24 17:52:03.286901: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f912d05cf60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-03-24 17:52:03.286913: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-03-24 17:52:07.450878: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke, so it turns out that the output of the network also gives the version and other parameters.

```
onnx_model = onnx.load(model_path)  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)

print(tf_rep.inputs) # Input nodes to the model
> output: ['visual_observation_0', 'visual_observation_1']
print(tf_rep.outputs) # Output nodes from the model
> output: ['version_number', 'memory_size', 'continuous_actions', 'continuous_action_output_shape', 'action', 'is_continuous_control', 'action_output_shape']
```

The input was like I expected. However the output also has version number, memory and so on. I'm only interested in the `continuous_actions`. I also had to scale the images between to [0, 1]